# FFmpeg open codec error when using "MobileVLCKit-prod" pod Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ffmpeg, vlc

I want to use VLCMediaPlayer into my project to live stream

I'm using `pod 'MobileVLCKit-prod'`

and this is my code

```
class CameraViewController: UIViewController,VLCMediaPlayerDelegate{

  var mediaPlayer = VLCMediaPlayer()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      mediaPlayer.delegate = self
      mediaPlayer.drawable = playerView
      let url = NSURL(string: "URL HERE")
      mediaPlayer.media = VLCMedia(URL: url!)
      mediaPlayer.play()
  }
}
```

When i run my app i got ffmpeg open codec error : [image: Screenshot of Codec Error]

Comment: You crash ffmpeg with invalid data.

Comment: No idea. You need to isolate data to reproduce the issue and open a ticket on the VLC or ffmpeg bug tracker.

Comment: Seems you don't have access to the video on that url. Are you able to access it via browser?